# htaccess redirect from https to http doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I'd like to redirect all my website URLs(with www) from https to http

Now with the code below it works only from https://www.example.it to http://www.example.it (and all other pages, for example: example.com/page02.php)

But doesn't work from https://example.com to http://example.com (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

This is the code I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Does someone know how do I do?

Comment: You said ,I'd like to redirect all my website URLs(with www) from https to http , then you said  doesn't work from https://example.com to http://example.com so, what you want exactly ? do you want to force all https into http  ?

Comment: Yes, I'd like that all the pages I have with HTTPS redirect to HTTP.

Comment: Do you have a valid ssl cert for your `www` subdomain?

Comment: I haven't the ssl cert that's why I'd like to redirect https to http

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Put rules after `RewriteEngine On` and clear browser cache then test

Comment: @Craig try updated one afetr clearing browser cache and paste your rules in question you may write something wrong

Comment: I even changed the computer (without any cache) but still have the error page with https://example.com